# Network access to VM only from host 

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows-xp, vmware-player

I'm trying to do some testing of Ubuntu 10.04 Beta 2 Server in a VMWare environment.  The host is XP, and the VM software is VMPlayer.

Problem is, I want to be able to see the VM from the network, not just from the host.  I can SSH into the VM from the host, but from any other machine on the network I can't even get the VM to respond to a ping.

Going the other way (from the VM out) isn't a problem at all.

The VM software did an 'easy installer' so I'm not really sure what was going on with the networking.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch guest OS's network to Bridged mode

Comment: @Jamie: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Change the NIC type to Bridged